# Self-modifying code in C: Use a function pointer?

Tags: c, function, pointers, self

I have a question about self-modifying code in C. I have a program that is written with C, and 
my goal is to change the power consumption with self-modifying code!

How can I write self-modifying code with C, that changes after each run specific instructions such as nop. Should I be using a function pointer in c for this?

Comment: Have you considered just using separate code paths depending on the desired power consumption, or is that not an option due to memory constraints?

Comment: I recently wrote a blog post about self-modifying C programs that you may find useful. It's way too long for an answer here though. https://shanetully.com/2013/12/writing-a-self-mutating-x86_64-c-program/

Comment: James O'Doherty i can't understand what 's your mean!i want after every run specific opcode(like NOP)in specific address change to other instrunctions like add,sub...

Comment: What do you mean when you talk about self modifying code?  Do you mean that you expect to modify the executable code in memory? or something else?

Comment: @shanet: You should post that on Code Review!

Answer (score 5):

No, there's no standard way of doing self-modifying code in C, it's not supported by the language.

There are "hacks", i.e. ways around the language, but they all require you to drop to the assembly level and trick around in order to overwrite memory containing code. There are issues with caches, write-protected code space, and more.

The only thing you can know about function pointers, to address this a bit better, is that they can be called. You cannot assume that the pointer is in any obvious way convertible into a pointer to the actual instructions, the language does not guarantee this (although most compilers on typical architectures will implement function pointers in "the obvious way").